# Seeding a foreign key using code first in c#

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, foreign-keys, entity-framework-migrations

I am having an issue on seeding my database and giving the foreign key a value.

This is my model for UserPains:

```
public partial class UserPain
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ScoredBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }

        public virtual Defect Defects { get; set; }

    }
```

This is my Defects model:

```
public partial class Defect
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

So when I seed with:

```
new UserPain { ScoredBy = 1, LastUpdated = DateTime.Now }
```

The value in the UserPain table labelled Defects_Id is null.  How could I assign the value of the Defects_Id to an id an existing defect in the defects table?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `Defect` property to a `Defect` instance you created or fetched from the database. Alternatively you can add an ID field to your `UserPain` object and set that instead:

```
public partial class UserPain
{
    // ...

    [Column("Defects_Id")]
    public int DefectId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DefectId")]
    public virtual Defect Defect { get; set; }

}
```

Now you can also set `DefectId` without an instance. I singularized the property name for you in the process!

Comment: So I added the ForeignKey tag above the public virtual Defect.  How do I address that in the seed for just the id, it gives me an option to set Defects equal to something, but it is expecting the defect model?

Comment: @Shawn: Err, set the `DefectId` field I also added?

Comment: hmm, I added both the attributes in the userpain model.  Got this when I tried to update-database - The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Comment: @Shawn: ...does the referenced ID exist in the database at the point where you save the changes?

Comment: The foreign key is in the right path, but the error at the end I am not sure about, where it says The conflict occurred in database "MyDB", table "dbo.Defects", column 'Id'.